# Forward email including headers using Python

Tags: python, datetime, email, outlook, win32com

i wrote a script to forward emails with the subject "ABC" from "John Smith". I also added my own text before i forward the email "today is a good day", however the problem is that the headers (From:, to:, subject etc) don't appear in the forwarded email when i send it. Appreciate if anyone can suggest a solution so i can forward the email with the headers.

```
import win32com.client
import time
import datetime as dt
from os import path

if not path.exists('testfile_cut.txt'):
    f = open("testfile_cut.txt", "w")
    f.write("07/17/20 00:00:00")
    f.close()

date_time = dt.datetime.now()

f = open("testfile_cut.txt", "r")
a = f.read()
a = dt.datetime.strptime(a, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
today = dt.date.today()
#date = str(datetime.now().date())[-5].replace('-','')

lastDayDateTime = dt.datetime.now() - a

lastDayDateTime = date_time - lastDayDateTime

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

messages = inbox.Items
sender = "john smith" 
sender = sender.lower() 
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)

lastDayMessages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + lastDayDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')+"'")

f = open("testfile_cut.txt","r")

a = f.read()
print(a)

b = lastDayMessages[0].ReceivedTime
b = dt.datetime.strftime(b, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
print(b)

if (b!=a):
    for message in lastDayMessages:
        if sender in message.SenderName.lower():
            if message.Subject.startswith("ABC"):
                print (message.ReceivedTime)
                print (message.SenderName.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
                print (message.Subject.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
                print (message.Body.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
                NewMsg = message.Forward()
                NewMsg.To = "Roger Smith"
                OrgBody = message.Body
                NewMsg.Body = "today is a good day" + str(OrgBody)
                NewMsg.Subject = "Activity as of - " + today.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
                NewMsg.Send()

                f.close()
               
                fl = open("testfile_cut.txt","w")
                fl.write(b)
                fl.close()

print ("Finished")
```

Comment: Do you see fields set correctly if you use `Display` instead of `Send`?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev No i don't see the fields when i use ```Display``` too

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the Body property - Forward() returns a message with the Body pre-populated with the original body and the message headers:

```
NewMsg.Body = "today is a good day\r\n" + str(NewMsg.Body)
```

You might also want to avoid the loop and update your restriction to include the restrcition on Subject.

Comment: That worked! How can I add multiple restrictions to avoid the loop?

Comment: Add a restriction on the subject. Search on subject does not work too well in OOM, you'd need to search on the PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT and PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME  MAPI properties using the SQL syntax: `@SQL=("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F" LIKE 'ABC%') and ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E060040" >= '06/01/2020 00:00AM')`